# Creating an array from a mysql table

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an automated log in system with cakePHP and need a bit of help working out how to get an array of possible log ins. At the moment I have this code, which means I have to manually add in the log in details each time a new user is needed:

```
$this->Security->loginUsers = array(
    'user1' => 'password1',
    'user2' => 'password2'
);
```

I have a mysql table called 'operators' which looks like this:

```
**Username     Password**
 user1      password1
 user2      password2
 user3      password3
```

etc. and this is automatically populated from a registration form. Could someone please tell me how I would turn the table into an array like the one above so that I can use it in the cakePHP code?

Thanks for any help

Edit: This is the code I have now but it doesn't work

```
    $test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM operators");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test))

    {

    $array = "'".$row['username']."' => '".$row['password']."'";


    }

$this->Security->loginUsers = $array;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM operators");

    $users = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test))
    {
        $users[ $row['username'] ] = $row['password'];
    }

    $this->Security->loginUsers = $users;
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual for PHP's [MySQLi-class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Hi Lukas, I have looked through the manual and altered my code but I can't get it working. Could you have a look at what I've done and tell me how to correct it please?

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work:

```
 $test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM operators");
 $results = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test))

    {

    $results['username'] = $row['password'];


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

so your using cakePHP right?
Does you 'operators' table have a model?
if so why not just:

```
$users = $this->Operator->find('list');
```

get a list out of the table - it should already be in an array just the way you want it.

Comment: I am using Cakephp but unfortunately I don't know how to use it and I am editing someone else's code...I'm going to try learning it soon

Comment: O.k so lets start learning it now... what model are you working in? if the model you are working in is linked to the 'Operator' model you can just use the line above to get all the information you want right into an array.